# React.js SyntaxError

Tags: reactjs

I'm reading Learning React by Alex Banks and Eve Porcello, published by O'Reilly Media now and I've received one issue.

From an example, in the book, I can't write this:

[image]

because I always receiving this Syntax Error:

[image]

Maybe it's the problem with the versions or some loader?

I just can't figure out this by myself.

I'll be very happy to see any reply.

Comment: Maybe this would help, there is a repository of this app ( https://github.com/MoonHighway/learning-react/tree/master/chapter-06/color-organizer ) my code not similar to this, but the issue is the same.

Comment: It's just a babel config problem, make sure you have -> `plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread`,  if your targeting modern browsers you won't need -> `babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread`, but if you are you will need this too.

Comment: please provide your `webpack.config.js` and `.babelrc`

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú , (webpack.config.js) http://prntscr.com/l18gjx , and .babelrc is just { "presets" : ["env", "react"] }

Comment: hm, @Keith, thank you for this reply, let me try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `babel-preset-stage-2` package and try this:

`.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react", "stage-2"]
}
```

Comment: Wow, you're right. 

I saw in some articles that this may help, but how this {stage-0, stage-1, stage-2} properly works? Maybe you can suggest some great article to read?

Comment: Note that the stage presets are being deprecated in Babel 7 - if you're using that version of Babel, you have to install plugins for individual unstable features you're using. In this case, it would be [`@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread). See [this blog post](https://babeljs.io/blog/2018/07/27/removing-babels-stage-presets) for the reasoning behind that.

Comment: @Andrew: The blog post I linked may also help you understand why the stage presets existed in the first place :)

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-2 and http://exploringjs.com/es2016-es2017/ch_tc39-process.html might be worth having a look at as well.

Comment: @Andrew No worries at all.